# Dominators when node not reachable

Tags: graphs, network-flow

For the definition of domination [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)),

> a node $d$ of a control-flow graph dominates a node $n$ if every path from the entry node to $n$ must go through $d$.

If node $n$ is not reachable from the entry node, **why are all other nodes *not* dominators for it?** There is no path from entry node that goes to $n$, and thus in particular

- there is no path from the entry node to $n$ that does **not** go through $d$.

Comment: According to the definition you posted, all nodes (including the entry node and $n$ itself) are dominators of $n$ when there is no path from the entry node to $n$. However I'm not sure if in control flow-graphs you can have nodes that are not reachable from the entry node in the first place.

Comment: @Steven, I see. Perhaps for an arbitrary graph, it would be most reasonable to define dominators if some path exists.

Comment: I don't expect the definitions on Wikipedia to be very precise. According to the definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph#Domination_relationship) a node always dominates itself, moreover an immediate dominator of $N$ is ``...the last dominator on all paths from entry to $N$'', which means that, for all nodes $N$ reachable from the entry node, the only immediate dominator of $N$ is $N$ itself. This is probably not what the author intended to define.

Comment: Huge thanks for your help @Steven!